# PyQt4 - connecting a button to a function - argument 1 has unexpected type, cannot convert to QObject

Tags: python, button, connection, signals, pyqt4

I'm new to python and PyQt4 and graphics at all.I want to be able to click on some kind of a button `play` and be able to start a new game, but I am experiencing some difficulties.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
class GameWindow(QtGui.QGraphicsView):
    def __init__(self):
        super(GameWindow, self).__init__()

        self.scene = QtGui.QGraphicsScene()
        self.scene.setSceneRect(0, 0, 470, 530)

        self.view = QtGui.QGraphicsView(self.scene)
        self.view.setFixedSize(470, 530)

    def start(self):
        pass 
        # some code about the new game

    def main_menu(self):
        playing = Button("Play")
        bx_pos = self.view.width()/2 - playing.boundingRect().width()/2
        by_pos = 275
        playing.setPos(bx_pos, by_pos)
        self.scene.addItem(playing)
        self.connect(playing, QtCore.SIGNAL('clicked()'), self,
                     QtCore.SLOT('start()'))
```

Also I post the relevant code for the Button class:

```
class Button(QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem):

    def __init__(self, name):
        super(Button, self).__init__()
        #and some other inializating stuff

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        super(Button, self).mousePressEvent(event)
```

It gives me:

```
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), QObject, SLOT(), Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Button'
QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), callable, Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Button'
QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), SLOT(), Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection): argument 1 has unexpected type 'Button'
```

I read that I must inherit from the QObject class to fix this. I tried doing it by changing "class Button(QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem)" to "class Button(QtGui.QGraphicsRectItem, QtCore.QObject)"    but now the problem is

```
**TypeError: could not convert 'Button' to 'QObject'**
```

I read some stuff about multiple inheritance, I guess that this is the problem, but I could not understand how to fix it, so I decided to ask here. 
Actually I'm not quite sure how should I define the mousePressEvent. That could also be a problem I suppose. If someone could help me, I would be very grateful :)

Comment: Why don't you simply use a `QPushButton` ? For the connect part, you should read [PyQt4 new style signals and slots](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html)

Comment: `def main_menu(self):  btn=QtGui.QPushButton("Play", self)  btn.clicked.connect(self.start)  btn.resize(150, 50)  btn.move(220, 170)  self.scene.addItem(btn)`  
If I do that it gives me  
**TypeError: QGraphicsScene.addItem(QGraphicsItem): argument 1 has unexpected type 'QPushButton'**
If I do just `self.show()` instead of  `self.scene.addItem(btn)`, the button pops up in a new window and I want it to be in the same window.

Comment: You shouldn't add the button to the graphic view. You should add the button and the graphic view to the main window. Here's a tutorial an [Layout management](http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/layoutmanagement/)

Comment: Thank you for the help. : )